# iPad Stops Charging Randomly

Tags: ipad, charging, power, lightning

My iPad Pro (12.9 inch first gen) will randomly stop charging, in the manner shown below, requiring me to unplug and plug back in the cable.

[image: not charging symbol]

Is there any way to stop this, because I can no longer charge overnight/away from my device, and I have to constantly check it to make sure it is charging.

Comment: What have you tried so far? New charger, new cable, cleaned connections?

Comment: I have tried a new wall adaptor and cleaned the connections, not a new cable because I dont have one on hand.

Comment: Then that would be the next test; followed by a reboot.

Comment: Ok, I'll buy a new cable and test that when i get a chance

Comment: Your iPad has a Lightning connector. Please try to use a needle to get dust out of the connector. There can be a lot of it even when the port looks clean to you. Be careful when doing it. Please try that before you buy new cable. I had this issue once and also bought a new cable - which did not solve the problem since the connector port was filled with dust.

Comment: @Arjihad I'll try that when I get home, I advise that you post it as an answer incase it does work, I can accept the answer etc.